# `synchronized` used differently

Tags: scala, scala-collections

While looking at [`scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedStack`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedStack.scala#L1) I've noticed that `synchronized` used differently, some methods use `synchronized[this.type]` form

```
override def push(elem: A): this.type = synchronized[this.type] { super.push(elem) }
override def pushAll(xs: TraversableOnce[A]): this.type = synchronized[this.type] { super.pushAll(elems) }
```

and some uses `synchronized` form

```
override def isEmpty: Boolean = synchronized { super.isEmpty }
override def pop(): A = synchronized { super.pop }
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of `synchronized` (declared by [`AnyRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html)) is

```
final def synchronized[T0](arg0: => T0): T0
```

If you use it as

```
override def isEmpty: Boolean = synchronized { super.isEmpty }
```

then you leave it to the compiler to infer the return type of the function passed to `synchronized` (here `Boolean`). If you use it as

```
override def push(elem: A): this.type = synchronized[this.type] {
  super.push(elem)
}
```

then you explicitly specify the return type (here `this.type`). I assume that the compiler will not infer `this.type` - which states that you return exactly `this` object -, but that it would infer `SynchronizedStack` or one of its supertypes, which is not as precise as `this.type`.

Comment: Right — the compiler does not infer singleton types.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Thanks for the clarification. Can you provide a reference, e.g., to the specs?

Comment: This is what I could find: [Singleton types are mean and spiteful](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6583).